# How can I change particle size by id of an already cached simulation?

Tags: python, particles, cache

I imported several simulations I made in Realflow and Maya, because I found out that Blenders wetmaps are much faster than other packages and I need to make a lot of them.

I'm completely new to Blender but I can grab the hang of it quickly, and already have everything setup. I just need to change each particle size randomly depending of their id, I'm thinking with python. In maya I already made similar things, yet I still haven't learned any commands for blender yet, can someone help me please?

Also, would it be possible to delete particles depending on their speed and/or age?

*Everything is already cached from the other softwares and I'm just importing them to blender using the realflow addon.*

I'm thinking something like this:

```
particleSystem="nameOfParticles"
particlesList=particleSystem[particles]
frames=xrange(1,100)
for f in frames:
    currentFrame(f)
    for part in particleList:
        randomSeed(part.id)
        setAttribute(part.size,rand(0,1))
        if (part.velocity>5) or (part.age>2):
            delete(part)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size of a particle randomly you can go to the physics tab in a particle system and change the random value.

[image]

If you want to look at the operators in python you can go to this link

[Python blender reference](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/)

If you want to delete a particle based on their age you can change the lifetime of the particle in the emission tab

[image]

Comment: yea i supposed, yet those attributes are greyed out and disabled, because its a cached simulation done in other software and just imported to blender, i need a way to do it at playback time using the info already cached